# Setting text within p tag with js variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, split

I am setting a text value within a p tag to a string being parsed out by splitting. When I alert the variable, I am able to see the text, however when I try to set the text to the variable value, I am unable to see a change. How do I edit this code to set the text within #view_head to the variables I pass within $('#view_head').text(//variable here//)?

The code

```
 $(edit_but).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        //e.preventDefault();
        //uses set input data to create variables for use in editor
        var master_string = $('#string_text').text();
        var key_string = master_string.split("|m|");
        var name_string = key_string[0].split("|s|");
        var cont_string = key_string[1].split("|s|");//contains contact variables
        var adr_string = key_string[2].split("|s|");
        var qual_string = key_string[3].split("|s|");//contains description and applying for blob text
        var pos_key_string = key_string[4].split("|s|");
        var edu_key_string = key_string[5].split("|s|");//key string to contain edu strings
        var course_key_string = key_string[6].split("|s|");
        var awd_key_string = key_string[7].split("|s|");
        var skill_key_string = key_string[8].split("|s|");
        var count_key_string ='';


        var pos_string = pos_key_string[0].split("|j|");

        alert (pos_key_string);   //working
        alert (name_string);
        $('#view_head').text(key_string); //not working, does not change
        alert (key_string); //working, can see value in alert for both


        //window.location = '#openModal';
    });
```

Comment: Use the snippet editor to create an actual example. Now we are just guessing. You are alerting pos_key_string but using key_string in the text(). Do you have a tag with `id="view_head"` ?

Comment: Yes, I have a p tag with "view_head" and I'm trying to set the text content within that tag to the variables found in the JavaScript. They are alerting fine, but the js does not change the text within the p tag.

Comment: `String.split()` returns an array, and `text()` waits for `Type: String or Number or Boolean`. Try to make it `$('#view_head').text(key_string.toString());`

Comment: I was afraid that was the case, so I was passing a string variable all along when the .text expected a string. Should toString turn the array into a readable string that would be valid for text?

Comment: Can you try to provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.split()` returns an array, and `.text()` waits for `Type: String or Number or Boolean.` - http://api.jquery.com/text/

Try to get it `$('#view_head').text(key_string.toString());` or `$('#view_head').text(key_string[0]);` if data, that you are looking for is in first array element.

Answer (score 0):

if text() is not working,maybe you could try val() or html()

Answer (score 0):

Using String`.split()` returns an Array object, which you cannot insert into an HTML element as text.  To create a String from an Array, which can be inserted into an HTML element, use the Array`.join()` method. EG.

```
var sample_string = "This is a String";

// split at spaces into an Array
var sample_array = sample_string.split(' ');
//--> ['This','is','a','String']

// join with spaces into a String
var another_string = sample_array.join(' ');
//--> "This is a String"
```

See MDN : [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) & [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)